# Replace spaces using function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-function

I'am currently developing a program and i want to write a function which is accept a value in following format

```
"AAAA BBBB"  CCCC DDDD EEEE "FFFF GGGG HHHH"
```

I want to replace the spaces in above with "_" and need a output as showed following format
(please note that this should happen only for string which is inside double quotes)

```
"AAAA_BBBB"  CCCC DDDD EEEE "FFFF_GGGG_HHHH"
```

can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the logic for it you could add to a function as you wanted.

```
DECLARE @In VARCHAR(50) = '"AAAA BBBB"  CCCC DDDD EEEE "FFFF GGGG HHHH"'

DECLARE @Quote SMALLINT = -1, @Index INT = 1, @Char CHAR(1)
WHILE @Index <= LEN(@In) BEGIN
    SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@In, @Index, 1)
    IF @Char = '"'
        SET @Quote = @Quote * -1
    IF @Char = ' ' AND @Quote > 0
        SET @In = STUFF(@In, @Index, 1, '_')
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

PRINT @In
```

**Output**

```
"AAAA_BBBB"  CCCC DDDD EEEE "FFFF_GGGG_HHHH"
```

Comment: Great answer.. thumbs up (y)

Comment: Hi @Jason W, I need to further extend this function and I expect your help.. please visit the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522911/sql-character-replace-function-extend